# Setting VS Code light/dark theme based on system's color scheme

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible to configure VS Code for automatically switching between a light theme and a dark theme based on system's chosen color scheme?

The behavior I'm looking for is similar to how the web apps can use media queries in the browser.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-color-scheme

```css
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  /* set dark theme colors */
}
```

Comment: how does the browser determine the Desktop theme and if that is a Dark/Light/HighContrast Theme, or is that based on the Browser Theme?

Comment: @rioV8 I'm not sure how browsers detect the system color scheme selected. Most likely every OS has an API to expose preferences. This seems to be how Electron does it:
[docs](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/native-theme)

[code](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/lib/browser/api/system-preferences.ts)

Comment: you should ask at the VSC repo if there is a possibility to get the `Electron::nativeTheme` available in the VSC API, the code link is just a deprecation message in case you use `systemPreferences` to get this info